# Auto excluding selector resembling a toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've being searching around and found some **jQuery** and **Vanilla** answers. I even found the exact answer to my problem, but it did not work within the rest of my code. So I have come with this adapted code which I took from this question [Show / Hide Div on Click with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539761/show-hide-div-on-click-with-javascript) and it works fine but...as far as it is when I choose and option it appears, fine, but I would like that if I select the other option, then the previous turns hidden. What I mean, I need only one of the options displayed at once. This is my code:

```js
function setCup(elementId) {
    const element = document.getElementById('pymntCup');

    if (element.style.display === "block") {
        element.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
    }
    function setUsd(elementId) {
    const element = document.getElementById('pymntUsd');

    if (element.style.display === "block") {
        element.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
    }
```

```css
.flag-icon-wrapper {
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    }
    .flex {
    display: flex;justify-content:space-evenly;
    }
    h3 {
    text-align:center;
    }
    .is-shown-initially {
    display: block;
    }
    .is-hidden-initially {
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<h3>Select a payment mode</h3>
    <div class="flex">
    <span class="flag-icon-wrapper flex" onClick='setCup()'>
    <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="22">
    <path d="m 40,3 v 7 h 3.3 q 3.4,0 3.4,-3 0,-3 -3.4,-4 z m 3.2,-3 q 3.3,0 5.1,2 1.7,2 1.7,5 0,3 -1.7,4 -1.7,2 -5,2 H 40 v 8 H 36.6 V 0 Z M 17.9,0 h 3.4 v 13 q 0,3 1,4 0.9,2 3,2 2,0 3,-1 1,-2 1,-5 V 0 h 3.3 v 13 q 0,5 -1.9,7 -1.8,2 -5.3,2 -3.6,0 -5.5,-2 -2,-2 -2,-7 z M 15.4,2 13.6,5 13.3,4 Q 11.4,3 9.3,3 6.5,3 4.9,5 3.4,7 3.4,11 q 0,8 5.9,8 2,0 3.8,-2 h 0.3 l 2,2 -0.5,1 Q 12.4,22 9.1,22 4.9,22 2.5,19 0,16 0,11 0,6 2.5,3 4.9,0 9.1,0 q 3.1,0 5.8,2 z" style="fill:#007aff;"/></svg>
    </span>
    <span class="flag-icon-wrapper flex" onClick='setUsd()'>
    <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="22">
    <path  d="m 37.2,3 v 15 h 2.5 q 3.7,0 5.3,-1 1.6,-2 1.6,-6 Q 46.6,7 45,5 43.4,3 39.7,3 Z m 2.2,-3 q 5.4,0 8,3 2.6,2 2.6,8 0,5 -2.6,8 -2.6,3 -8,3 H 33.8 V 0 Z M 24.6,3 q -1.4,0 -2.1,1 -0.8,1 -0.8,2 0,1 0.4,2 0.5,0 1.8,1 h 1.6 q 2.7,1 3.9,2 1.2,2 1.2,5 0,3 -1.9,4 -1.9,2 -5.2,2 -1.3,0 -2.8,-1 -1.5,0 -2.7,-1 l 2.3,-3 q 1.5,2 3.3,2 1.7,0 2.6,-1 1,-1 1,-2 0,-2 -0.5,-2 -0.6,-1 -1.9,-1 L 23.2,12 Q 18.3,11 18.3,6 18.3,4 20,2 21.8,0 24.6,0 v 0 q 3,0 5.2,3 L 27.6,5 Q 27.4,5 27.2,5 27,4 26.1,4 25.4,3 24.6,3 Z M 0,0 h 3.4 v 13 q 0,3 0.9,5 0.9,1 3.2,1 2,0 3,-1 1.1,-2 1.1,-5 V 0 h 3.3 v 14 q 0,4 -1.9,6 -1.9,2 -5.5,2 Q 3.9,22 1.9,20 0,18 0,14 Z" style="fill:#007aff;"/></svg>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
    <div id="pymntCup" class="is-hidden-initially">
    <ul>
        <li>Pagos desde Cuba</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pymntUsd" class="is-hidden-initially">
    <ul>
        <li>Payments from the World</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can set the other one to none

```
function setCup(elementId) {
const element = document.getElementById('pymntCup');

//Here you can set the other one to none 
document.getElementById('pymntUsd').style.display = "none";

if (element.style.display === "block") {
    element.style.display = "none";
} else {
    element.style.display = "block";
}

}
```

Likewise here too

```
function setUsd(elementId) {
const element = document.getElementById('pymntUsd');

//Here you can set the other one to none 
document.getElementById('pymntCup').style.display = "none";

if (element.style.display === "block") {
    element.style.display = "none";
} else {
    element.style.display = "block";
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, but the previous was more based on my own code so it was easier to implement. Yours is valid too

Comment: I finally implemented this answer and it worked as expected within my code. So I accepted as a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

You have logic errors in code that hides items. Fixed code:

```js
let cupElement, usdElement;

window.onload = () => {
  cupElement = document.getElementById('pymntCup');
  usdElement = document.getElementById('pymntUsd');
}

function setCup() {
  cupElement.style.display = cupElement.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
  usdElement.style.display = "none";
}

function setUsd() {
  cupElement.style.display = "none";
  usdElement.style.display = usdElement.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```css
.flag-icon-wrapper {
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    }
    .flex {
    display: flex;justify-content:space-evenly;
    }
    h3 {
    text-align:center;
    }
    .is-shown-initially {
    display: block;
    }
    .is-hidden-initially {
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<h3>Select a payment mode</h3>
    <div class="flex">
    <span class="flag-icon-wrapper flex" onClick='setCup()'>
    <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="22">
    <path d="m 40,3 v 7 h 3.3 q 3.4,0 3.4,-3 0,-3 -3.4,-4 z m 3.2,-3 q 3.3,0 5.1,2 1.7,2 1.7,5 0,3 -1.7,4 -1.7,2 -5,2 H 40 v 8 H 36.6 V 0 Z M 17.9,0 h 3.4 v 13 q 0,3 1,4 0.9,2 3,2 2,0 3,-1 1,-2 1,-5 V 0 h 3.3 v 13 q 0,5 -1.9,7 -1.8,2 -5.3,2 -3.6,0 -5.5,-2 -2,-2 -2,-7 z M 15.4,2 13.6,5 13.3,4 Q 11.4,3 9.3,3 6.5,3 4.9,5 3.4,7 3.4,11 q 0,8 5.9,8 2,0 3.8,-2 h 0.3 l 2,2 -0.5,1 Q 12.4,22 9.1,22 4.9,22 2.5,19 0,16 0,11 0,6 2.5,3 4.9,0 9.1,0 q 3.1,0 5.8,2 z" style="fill:#007aff;"/></svg>
    </span>
    <span class="flag-icon-wrapper flex" onClick='setUsd()'>
    <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="22">
    <path  d="m 37.2,3 v 15 h 2.5 q 3.7,0 5.3,-1 1.6,-2 1.6,-6 Q 46.6,7 45,5 43.4,3 39.7,3 Z m 2.2,-3 q 5.4,0 8,3 2.6,2 2.6,8 0,5 -2.6,8 -2.6,3 -8,3 H 33.8 V 0 Z M 24.6,3 q -1.4,0 -2.1,1 -0.8,1 -0.8,2 0,1 0.4,2 0.5,0 1.8,1 h 1.6 q 2.7,1 3.9,2 1.2,2 1.2,5 0,3 -1.9,4 -1.9,2 -5.2,2 -1.3,0 -2.8,-1 -1.5,0 -2.7,-1 l 2.3,-3 q 1.5,2 3.3,2 1.7,0 2.6,-1 1,-1 1,-2 0,-2 -0.5,-2 -0.6,-1 -1.9,-1 L 23.2,12 Q 18.3,11 18.3,6 18.3,4 20,2 21.8,0 24.6,0 v 0 q 3,0 5.2,3 L 27.6,5 Q 27.4,5 27.2,5 27,4 26.1,4 25.4,3 24.6,3 Z M 0,0 h 3.4 v 13 q 0,3 0.9,5 0.9,1 3.2,1 2,0 3,-1 1.1,-2 1.1,-5 V 0 h 3.3 v 14 q 0,4 -1.9,6 -1.9,2 -5.5,2 Q 3.9,22 1.9,20 0,18 0,14 Z" style="fill:#007aff;"/></svg>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
    <div id="pymntCup" class="is-hidden-initially">
    <ul>
        <li>Pagos desde Cuba</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pymntUsd" class="is-hidden-initially">
    <ul>
        <li>Payments from the World</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've got an issue. As I integrated your solution within my project it shows this error "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "style", cupElement is null" May this be due to the fact that I'm developing an MVC project? It works perfectly as it's but gives that error on my project. What can be causing it?